# How to prevent overlap of inset y axis labels with data columns in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Although I was able to identify and configure my Higharts chart to have y-axis labels inset into the plot area, I was unable to prevent them from overlapping the data columns, like in the example bellow.

Given Highcharts has a lot of configuration options, I presume there’s a way to prevent that overlap, either by “reserving space” for the y-axis labels, or by adjusting the plot area, or yet other conceivable ways.

My expectation is that the gap between columns would reduce further as more data points are added, and that no column would ever position itself underneath the y-axis labels. In other words, I expect the plot area to start a little bit further to the right, somehow accounting for the width of the y-axis labels.

Would this be possible?

See the current result, the expected napkin sketch, and my configuration file.

[Current overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM0oE.png)

[Expected result from NY Times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WhwD.png)

[CodePen example](https://codepen.io/liragilmar/pen/dyqegey)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    height: 320,
    width: 452,
    style: {

        fontFamily: 'Inter var',
      },
  },  
  title: {
    align: 'left',
    margin: 40,
    style: {
      fontSize: 14,
      fontWeight: 'bold',      
    },
    text: 'Cash balance reducing linearly'
  },
  subtitle: {
    align: 'left',
    style: {
      fontSize: 13,
      color: '#797675'
    },
    text: 'Cash balance has been predictable for the past 5 months'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: [
      "Something long",
      "Something long",
      "Something long",
      "Something long",
      "Something long",
      "Something long",
    ],
    labels: {
      autoRotation: undefined,
      style: {
        color: '#3d3b3b'
      },
    }
  },
  yAxis: {    
    min: 0,
    labels: {
      align: 'left',            
      autoRotation: undefined,
      reserveSpace: false,
      style: {
        color: '#3d3b3b'
      },
      x: 4,
      y: -4,
      format: '${text}',
      formatter: ''
    },    
    plotLines: [
      {
        color: '#000',
        width: 1,
        value: 0,
        zIndex: 4,
      }
    ],
    title: {
      align: 'high',
      margin: 0,
      reserveSpace: false,
      rotation: 0,
      style: {
        color: '#3d3b3b'
      },
      text: 'Cash (millions)',
      textAlign: 'left',
      x: 40,
      y: -4
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0.3,
      groupPadding: 0,
      borderWidth: 0,
      maxPointWidth: 40,
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Cash balance',
      type:'column',
      data: [
        12541723, 
        12261236, 
        11956359, 
        11624971, 
        11956359, 
        11624971, 
        11956359, 
        11624971, 
        11264766
      ],
      pointWidth: 30,
      yAxis: 0
    }
  ],
  colors: ['#79c298'],
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  }
});
```

P.S: I could also simulate the desired result by cheating a bit, and adding one initial `0` value to the data set:

[Simulation of desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXzPE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this by using longer ticks. Changes will include setting length, width and color of the tick. Because of the `xAxis.line` different color, you will also need to change color for the first tick seperately.

**Example code:**

```
 chart: {
    events: {
      load() {
       // Change color of the first yAxis tick
        this.yAxis[0].ticks[0].mark.attr({
          stroke: '#ccd6eb'
        });
      }
    },
    ...
  },
 yAxis: {
    tickLength: 40,
    tickWidth: 1,
    tickColor: '#e6e6e6',
    labels: {
       align: 'left',
       ...
    }
    ...
  },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6tgevja9/

Comment: Brilliant! This solves the puzzle completely. Thank you, @magdalena!